# Flutter 2.0 - Web - Force desktop mode (because they are displayed differently)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter2.0

the app from chrome on desktop and mobile are different. the correct one is the one from desktop. the app on the mobile device (in this case iOS) has the images cut out from the screen or completely moved, plus there is a sort of zoom. If from Safari on mobile I select "Request Desktop Website" the site is displayed entirely and correctly. how can i force this default setting in flutter 2.0 web?

Comment: did you find some solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, i will try with the new flutter updates

Answer (score 0):

Probably will need to feed in the platform density property to your material app https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VisualDensity/adaptivePlatformDensity.html

Comment: VisualDensity.compact is the default density property for the desktop application but it doesn't work.